# C++: typedefing and nested class issue

Tags: c++, class

I have:

```
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    ....
private:
    struct TP_Thread: public Thread_t
    {
        ....
    };
    std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<TP_Thread> >   m_threads;
   .....
};
```

I wanna do something like:

```
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<TP_Thread> shpThread;
```

to shorten the writing in the class definitions. Problem is I either get pointer to incomplete type (because of forward declaration before the class and typedef  the public section) or trying to access a private member of ThreadPool (in the case I'm trying to typedef it outside the class). How can I typedef this so I can use it freely during implementations?

Comment: Why not simply put the typedef in the private section?

Comment: I want it to be accesible to users of the class

Comment: Can you typedef the base class `Thread_t` instead? Your `TP_Thread` is private, it is not accessible to the users anyway.

Comment: You know you can have multiple "public"/"private" sections, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not including your typedef in a public section of the class:

```
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    ....
private:
    struct TP_Thread: public Thread_t
    {
        ....
    };
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<TP_Thread> Shp;
    ...
```

then use `ThreadPool::Shp` in your code.